# Determine what is on a device in Mac OSX

Tags: mac

I have a device /dev/disk0s1. How do I determine what it is?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

On a command line:

```
diskutil info /dev/disk0s1
```

Strictly speaking, disk0s1 is a slice (partition). disk0 is a device.

Comment: Out of curiosity, is that a Mac only command or is it available on linux as well?

Comment: diskutil is a Mac-specific command. Strictly speaking, it is the command line version of Disk Utility